# SQL Server query having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, having-clause

In below query I am getting error after `HAVING` clause. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Select round(TaxableAmount,0) as t, round(((TaxValue*100)/TaxPercentage),0)as t2 from VoucherTaxDetail where 
TaxPercentage<>0 and TaxableAmount>0 and TableName in('TVPayment','Payment') group by transactionId having t<>t2
```

Comment: SELECT ROUND(TAXABLEAMOUNT, 0)                         AS T, 
       ROUND(( ( TAXVALUE * 100 ) / TAXPERCENTAGE ), 0)AS T2 
FROM   VOUCHERTAXDETAIL 
WHERE  TAXPERCENTAGE <> 0 
       AND TAXABLEAMOUNT > 0 
       AND TABLENAME IN( 'TVPAYMENT', 'PAYMENT' ) 
GROUP  BY TRANSACTIONID 
HAVING ROUND(TAXABLEAMOUNT, 0) <> ROUND(( ( TAXVALUE * 100 ) / TAXPERCENTAGE ),0)

Comment: @Chanukya please delete the comment and post it as an answer explaining to the PO what you did

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? (I see no aggregate functions...)

Comment: I presume this query worked in MySQL and you thought wth...

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server requires that you repeat the expression in the `HAVING` clause (or use a CTE or subquery).  You have no aggregation functions, so I presume you intend:

```
select round(sum(TaxableAmount), 0) as t,
       round(sum(TaxValue*100/TaxPercentage), 0) as t2
from VoucherTaxDetail
where TaxPercentage <> 0 and TaxableAmount > 0 and
      TableName in ('TVPayment', 'Payment')
group by transactionId
having round(sum(TaxableAmount), 0) <> round(sum(TaxValue*100/TaxPercentage), 0);
```

Comment: Thats great!! its working thanks for answer but it is doing same thing as it i have done in my answers query. Check out what i have found below. I have done it using WITH clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use column aliases in the `HAVING` clause. The trick is to wrap the query up as a *derived table* (sub-query). Then you can have those aliases in the outer `WHERE` clause.

```
select *
from
(
    select round(TaxableAmount,0) as t, round(((TaxValue*100)/TaxPercentage),0)as t2
    from VoucherTaxDetail 
    where  TaxPercentage<>0 and TaxableAmount>0 and TableName in('TVPayment','Payment')
    group by transactionId
) dt
where t<>t2
```

Comment: @SalmanA, you mean the GROUP BY comment? Well, at least this shows how to use column aliases in a where clause.

Comment: The above is not working and giving the below error. Column 'VoucherTaxDetail.TaxableAmount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

However, i found this answer for my query. I just thought of using the output of the inner query with WITH clause and CTE. 
Basically, what i have understood that we cannot use the output of alias in HAVING clause for applying conditions.

```
 with cte as (
 Select round(TaxableAmount,0) as t,
 round(((TaxValue*100)/TaxPercentage),0)as t2 
 from VoucherTaxDetail where
 TaxPercentage<>0 and TaxableAmount>0 and TableName in('TVPayment','Payment'))
 select * from cte where t<>t2
```

Comment: A good answer has a better explanation [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.